# How do I avoid undefined when finding a limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \left[\frac {1}{x\sqrt{1+x}} - \frac {1}{x}\right]$$
I applied the difference law to separate out the two parts, but I still can't use direct substitution because it comes out undefined. I can't figure out how to rearrange the equations to get to direct substitution from here. 
The limit I found from my graphing calculator is -.5, but I have to do it algebraically :(

Comment: @bye_World idk how to get it to display properly but that is not the equation ... it would be put in the calculator as (1/(x sqroot 1+x)) - (1/x)) and what I mean by x sqroot 1+x is x times the square root of 1=x. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Bye_World thanks!!! thats what it's supposed to be :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fill in details:

$$\frac1{x\sqrt{1+x}}-\frac1x=\frac{1-\sqrt{1+x}}{x\sqrt{1+x}}=\frac{-x}{x\sqrt{1+x}(1+\sqrt{1+x})}=$$

$$=-\frac1{\sqrt{1+x}+1+x}\xrightarrow[x\to0]{}-\frac12$$

Except the last one, which is directly arithmetic of limits, all the other steps are simply algebra.

Answer (score 0):

The application of difference law is invalid here. If you look carefully the statement of difference law you will find that the law applies only when the limit of both the terms involved in a difference exist. Here we see that both the terms $1/x$ and $1/x\sqrt{1 + x}$ don't have a limit as $x \to 0$ and therefore the difference law does not apply.

It is a very typical mistake made by beginners in calculus. *The laws of algebra of limits can be applied only in the circumstances where they are applicable and students often fail to notice the conditions under which these laws are applicable*.

---

Now that the difference law (or algebra of limits) does not apply here what do we do? We transform the expression in a manner so that it is possible to apply algebra of limits. Thus we can see that if $x \neq 0$ then $$f(x) = \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 + x}}{x\sqrt{1 + x}}$$ and you can see that the quotient rule of limit can not be applied here because the denominator tends to $0$. Thus you need further transformation of the above expression. You can multiply by $1 + \sqrt{1 + x}$ in both numerator and denominator and after simplification you will get $$f(x) = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x}\{1 + \sqrt{1 + x}\}}$$ and by algebra of limits this tends to $-1/2$ as $x \to 0$.

Answer (score -1):

In general, this situation is called an *indeterminate form*; a situation where just plugging in the numbers doesn't do the trick. In this case, the form is $\infty - \infty$. An indeterminate form is a clue that you have to do some sort of simplification or something sneaky in order to get the limit. Usually you can tell what the trick's going to be by looking at the form. In this case, those $\infty$'s look like they "should" cancel. Of course they don't, but we can take inspiration from that and look for ways of making things cancel. The best way to do that is to compound everything into one fraction, and hope. $\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1+x}} - \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1 - \sqrt{1+x}}{x\sqrt{1+x}}$. Still no good - if we plug in $0$, we get $0/0$, which is another indeterminate form. So we have to play around with it a bit more. From here, I'll let you fill in the details.

After some more simplification, if you do it the way I did, you'll get $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x} + 1 + x}$, which is *not* indeterminate - plug in $0$ and you get $-\frac{1}{2}$. So that's your answer.